# uiLabel in another viewcontroller is not updated when uicollectionview cell select

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I placed an UIcollectionview in a viewcontroller (working successfully).
I want to open another viewcontroller and update the label in this vc with the selected cell text.
I am using following code but it's not working (not updating the label in other vc):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// gorseldetay is another viewcontroller including a label and an image
NSLog(@"Row : %d , Section : %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
gorselDetay *g = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gorselDetay"];
NSLog(@"%@",g.mylabel2.text); // returns "null"
g.mylabel2.text = @"any text to update";
NSLog(@"%@", g.mylabel2.text); // returns "null"
}
```

and I also added prepareForSegue action

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier); // returns "showDetail", OK

 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    UIImage *imageim2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyimage.png"]; //this file exists

    gorselDetay *r1 = (gorselDetay * )[segue destinationViewController];
    [r1.mylabel2 setText:@"any text to update"];
    r1.gorselim.image = imageim2;
    NSLog(@"2 - %@", r1.mylabel2.text); // returns "null"
}
}
```

As I said above, UICollectionView is successfully populated and working OK but the label in another viewcontroller (named gorselDetay) is not updated. But gorselDetay vc succesfully opens by the way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update a label (or other UI elements) this way from another controller because its view hasn't been loaded yet (r1.myLabel2 will be null). You need to pass the text to a string property in r1, and then set the label's text with that property in r1's viewDidLoad.

Comment: <Instance variable "any_variable_name" is protected> error returns when I try to update the variable in other vc.